# R replicate function returns a numeric matrix instead of a list of 'zoo' type

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a function that generates a "random" time series and returns a zoo object:

```
f = makeTrace()
{
...details...
  trace = zoo(g, dt)
}
```

I then call this generating function with replicate to generate many of these random time series:

```
make2DHist <- function(N=1000, alignG = .5, log=TRUE )
{
    v = replicate(10, makeTrace()) 
    v
    }
```

Now if I print out the result of d=make2DHist() I get

```
> class(d)
[1] "matrix"
```

And if I print out d, I see a matrix of values. Yet if I run the time series generator function and store that in a variable I do indeed get a 'zoo' class member.

```
> d = makeTrace()
> class(d)
[1] "zoo"
```

How can I generate an arbitrary number of time series and store them together? I looked over the replicate help pages but didn't see anything about this, and there's not much on so about the replicate function.

Second, related question. I want to make a 2d histogram of these time series (time vs. value). The easiest way seems to be to convert the zoo objects into two-column data frames and then rbind all the data frames together and then use hist2d. But this seems inelegant. Is there another way to do this, preferably using zoo objects rather than having to convert to data frames?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use the simplify argument--set it to FALSE.

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I would mark this as an answer, but I'm not getting that option on the interface.

Comment: You can ping a specific user like so: @AnandaMahto, do you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sorry. On my phone.... Hope the answer is sufficient as written. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `simplify` argument for `replicate` is set to `TRUE`. This means that the function checks to see whether the results are conformable to a matrix, and if it is, it returns a `matrix` instead of a `list`.

To override this behavior, set `simplify = FALSE` in your `replicate` function.